# Extracting data from domain

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
host = 'unw.us.co'
data1 = host.find('.')
print(data1)
data2 = host.find('.', data1)
print(data2)
data3 = host[data1+1 : data2 ]
print(data3)
```

I am trying to extract the country code in this example but for some reason, if I use find twice on periods(.) it is incorrect whereas if I use the code below it works fine. Can I refactor the above code instead of using the code below?

```
host = 'unw.us.co'
data1 = host.find('.')
print(data1)
data2 = host.find('.', data1)
print(data2)
data3 = host[data1+1 : data2+ 3 ]
print(data3)
```

I am trying to extract country codes out of the email domains.

Answer (score 0):

To find the second period you have to start one past where you found the first one:

```
host = 'unw.us.co'
data1 = host.find('.')
print(data1)
data2 = host.find('.', data1 + 1)  # +1 here
print(data2)
data3 = host[data1+1 : data2 ]
print(data3)
```

Output:

```
3
6
us
```

Or more refactored:

```
host = 'unw.us.co'
start = host.find('.') + 1
end = host.find('.', start)
country = host[start:end]
print(country)
```

You can also split the string on periods and take the second item:

```py
host = 'unw.us.co'
print(host.split('.')[1])  # Output: us
```